# How can I make a circle bounce in a window?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I just made this program as a practice I want to make the circle bounce from end to end which I came up in this source codes can you make if happen.

```
import PyQt5,sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QTimer,QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication,QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter

class Circle(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(250,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Bounce-Man")
        self.color = Qt.red
        self.fixedplace = 125
        self.mover = 450


    def paintEvent(self,event):
        bouncer.setPen(Qt.black)
        bouncer.setBrush(self.color)
        bouncer.drawEllipse(QPoint(self.fixedplace,self.mover),50,50)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot() 
    def timer(self):    
        timer = QTimer()
        while self.mover >=50:
            timer.start(1000)
            if self.mover == 50:
                self.mover = 450
            self.mover -= 1
            self.update()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = Circle()
    app.show()
sys.exit( window.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a QTimer to call a function that updates the position, do not use a while loop:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Circle(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Circle, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(250,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Bounce-Man")
        self.color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red)
        self.rect_circle = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 50, 50)
        self.rect_circle.moveCenter(QtCore.QPoint(self.width()/2, self.rect_circle.height()/2))
        self.step = QtCore.QPoint(0, 5)
        self.y_direction = 1

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=30)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update_position)
        timer.start()

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        bouncer = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        bouncer.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        bouncer.setBrush(self.color)
        bouncer.drawEllipse(self.rect_circle)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_position(self):
        if self.rect_circle.bottom() > self.height() and self.y_direction == 1:
            self.y_direction = -1
        if self.rect_circle.top() < 0 and self.y_direction == -1:
            self.y_direction = 1
        self.rect_circle.translate(self.step * self.y_direction)
        self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    window = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = Circle()
    app.show()
    sys.exit( window.exec_() )
```

Comment: can i ask for what is the initiation of parent?